# AWS IAM: Finding it hard to design a authorization model for SAML-based users

Tags: amazon-web-services, authorization, amazon-iam

Background: On Azure (we're in the process of moving from azure to aws), we have everything organized into resources groups. By default no one can do much in the prod subscription(account), but based on the team asking for a provisioned resource, a team member gets stamped as the "owner" of the resource group, which just gives him/her full access to that resource group, and can add/remove other members as they see fit. This allows us to set up a very fine-grained set of access controls where each team ultimately decides whats allowed and not - not based on groups but based on users getting access to resource groups (in which instances and other resources exist).

Now that we're moving to AWS I had hoped to use the SAML integration to provide access (we're running Auth0 in front of AzureAD, but this should be the same for any saml/federated aws setup I think). 
My problem is that with SAML AWS doesn't really "see" each individual user - they're not auto-created in IAM at first logon or anything, so the only "security boundary" I have to work with are the groups I send into AWS, which I can assign to IAM roles.

This is a problem, because 1)the user has to select the desired role at login (if member of more than one), and 2)each role setup is a manual task which requires me to configre AzureAD, saml claims in auth0 and finally IAM roles in AWS. The latter is obviously something I can automate, but still.

Here's the core of my problem:
Say that I have 2 EC2 instances in AWS: DB and Web. I have 3 users, AdminPete, DBDave and WebWilson. I'd like to be able to give Pete full access to both instances, while Dave and Wilson gets access to "their own" ec2 instance. As far as I can see, I would have to configure two IAM roles (DB and Web), and require Pete (who has access to both) to choose his role at login. This is a super-simple example, but it doesn't really scale well at all.

I'm curious to hear how you guys are doing access control in aws - my goal is to be able to create a very fine-tuned setup using tags or some other mechanism. The official aws documentation only deals with getting saml configured (which is easy enough), but very little about real-life permissions management.

The core of the problem (imho) is that unlike "regular" iam users, I can't attach an iam policy or a group to a single user when that user is federated - I can only attach the policy to the federated role as a whole.

Any pointers appreciated! At this point I'm considering just not using saml at all for our aws stuff so that we can use fine-grained iam policies to manage permissions in a more flexible manner.

Comment: I would go down the ABAC (fine-grained IAM policy) way you mention. Amazon has a pretty decent language